# fswatch: update file permissions on creation

Tags: bash, shell-script, osx

I have a directory and I want when a new file or directory is created inside to update their permissions.

For now, I achieved to do it with `fswatch` and new file/directory creation is detected, however when I change permission, script is called again so I get an infinite loop

```
#!/bin/bash

fswatch -0 -r --event Created /path/to/my/directory \
| while read -d '' file; do \
    echo "file: ${file}"

    if [[ -d ${file} ]] ; then
      chown xxxx:staff "${file}"
      chmod 770 "${file}"
    elif [[ -f ${file} ]]; then
      chown xxxx:staff "${file}"
      chmod 775 "${file}"
    fi
done
```

This script is used on macOS High Sierra.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I tried a bare `fswatch -r /path/to/my/directory` on a macOS system,
and it turns out that *something* is causing the `chmod` and `chown`
calls to sometimes report a `Created` event (in addition to
`OwnerModified` and `IsFile`). I even got stray `Removed` events,
presumably from deleting the test files prior to starting fswatch.

Running on Linux (using the inotify monitor) did not exhibit this
behavior: chmod triggers an `AttributeModified` event, and nothing
else.

This was very surprising to me, and explains the behavior you have
been observing (and which I have been able to reproduce). This is
apparently documented behavior; the fswatch GitHub repository has a
[closed "can't fix" issue about
this](https://github.com/emcrisostomo/fswatch/issues/108):

> If different events originate from the same file on a short period
>   of time, then multiple events may carry information about the same
>   event. (...) `fswatch` cannot do anything about it.

The issue page linked above also proposes some workarounds, none of
which seem very satisfactory. Perhaps, in your case, checking existing
permissions and ownerships prior to applying chmod and chown,
respectively, would help.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I updated my script by adding some tests on permissions, but he is still triggered multiples times : https://pastebin.com/LLbsvQPP (`chmod` is lauched once but not `chown`)

Comment: Edit: this line cause multiple launch : `if [[ $user != $new_user || $group != $new_group ]]`
When I do it with 2 distincts `if`, everything is working fine.